# How to write Javascript code for HTML helpers ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an HTML helper textBox like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("txt1") <br />
```

Now I want to fire a javascript `onchange` event on this textbox. Is it possible to do so or should I use an HTML input type instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify html attributes using the htmlAttributes parameter of the TextBox Html helper method like so:

```
@Html.TextBox("txt1", null, new { onchange="..." })
```

See: [InputExtensions.TextBox Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049.aspx)

From the above link:

> The htmlAttributes parameter consists of an object that contains
>   name/value pairs. The attributes that are specified in the name/value
>   pairs depend on the HTML element that is being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID for this textbox, you can hook the event to the textbox using Jquery.

```
$("#textboxid").keydown(function(event) {
    alert("Hey!");
});
```

Note that I've used the Keydown event. You can also use press or up events.

Or you can make the binding in the ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#textboxid").bind("onchange", yourfunction);
          });
```